# How to do a global string array in vba?

Tags: vba

i'm working on access and i need to send strings from one form to another, so i'd like to use a string() but the application don't want it.

Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

I have a form with 2 text box, each text box will take data with the same syntax, like textbox1:"JOHN" textbox2: "DAVID"
I have and add button for each text box who stock each value in different array.
The adds buttons are checking if the value of each textbox exists in 2 differents tables, table1 for textbox1 and table2 for textbox2.
If it exists i need to keep them until a user press an other button who load a second form.
The user can set an infinite numbers of value in each text box, by pressing add when he set a new value.

And when i load this second form i need to keep the values who exists in each table but separatly for to load in 2 subform some datas based on each values.

All is working except i don't know how to pass 2 arrays from form 1 to form 2, array 1 with values of textbox1, and array 2 with values from textbox2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass it when the form loads, you can concatenate the values to a single string and pass it through the `.OpenArgs`.

On the other form's load event, you can split the string and create an array.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, "String1;String2;String3;String4"

'...

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim arr As Variant
    With Me
        If Not IsNull(.OpenArgs) Then
            arr = Split(.OpenArgs, ";")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

### Update 1:

You can build the `.OpenArgs` string like this:

```
dim oneString as String

With Me
    oneString = .YourtextBoxName1.Value & ";" & .YourtextBoxName2.Value 'etc...
End With

DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, oneString
```

### Update 2:

Place this in a Standard Module:

```
Private mArrValues() As Variant

'ArrayValues
Public Property Get ArrayValues() As Variant
    ArrayValues = mArrValues()
End Property

'Add value to array
Public Sub AddToArrayValues(ByVal index As Integer, value As String)
    ReDim Preserve mArrValues(0 To index)
    mArrValues(index) = value
End Sub

'Erase
Public Sub EraseArrayValues()
    Erase mArrValues
End Sub
```

You can add values to the array like this:

```
Module1.AddToArrayValues 0, "Thomas"
Module1.AddToArrayValues 1, "Henry"
Module1.AddToArrayValues 2, "Bob"
```

You can retrieve values by index:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(Module1.ArrayValues) To UBound(Module1.ArrayValues)
    Debug.Print Module1.ArrayValues(i)
Next i

'Thomas
'Henry
'Bob
```

Do forget you need to erase the array before refilling it:

```
Module1.EraseArrayValues
```

Comment: Thank you, it was what i was looking for.
Isn't possible to use a public string() in vba ?

Comment: It is but what’s the point for such overhead if you’re only planning to use it once? Public variables are loaded in memory when your app starts and stay there until the app’s terminated. I personally avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: I understand this, but i need to share 2 type of string, i can't know what string will be of each format exemple 
string 1 = "exemple1"
string 2 = "exemple2"
So for to separate each i must use a second identifier like "?exemple1" and "!exemple2" ? I will have something like 10 string in each array

Comment: Where do your strings come from?

Comment: From 2 text box on my main form, currently i stock them separatly

Comment: The update doesn't really help, i have updated my question in the subject